# What timestamp is it?

Tags: sqlite, timestamp

What timestamp is it?
41056.2752083333 is 14:36 May 27, 2012 GMT+7
41056.2967361111 is 15:07 May 27, 2012 GMT+7
It is from sqlite3 database taken from icq v.7

---

EDIT

---

So, thank for the answer.
Here is the func to convert timestamp in icqv7 format to Python's struct_time:

```
f = lambda x: time.localtime(x*86400-2208988800-172800+3600)
```

where 2208988800 is the number or seconds between 1 Jan 1900 and 1 Jan 1970,
172800 is the number of seconds in two days,
and 3600 is one hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's the number of days since the first of January 1900, midnight UTC.

EDIT: Oops - it looks like it's actually two days out, which is very odd. It clearly *is* a number of days though, as the difference between 41056.2752083333 and 41056.2967361111 is 0.0215277778, which is 31 minutes when taken as "a number of days".

So it looks like you just need to adjust the epoch slightly - with an epoch of December 30th 1899, I get a date/time for the first value of 2012-05-27T06:36:00Z - there's still an hour discrepancy there, but I *suspect* that may be due to the way you're diagnosing the date/time rather than anything else. Do you have any values in December, for example?

Comment: @ekini: Looks right to me - what makes you think it's not? (Put it this way, in .NET when I added 41056.2752083333 days to January 1st 1900 UTC, I got the right value...)

Comment: @ekini: See my edit - looks like I may have been a couple of days out, but the basic approach is correct.

Comment: I've got only these two values. Hope that formula will work with any timestamp.